# What produces Magnetic Intensity H in a bar magnet?

Tags: magnetic-fields

[image]

Here I have added a section from Griffith's Book. It says that H need not be zero when the free current is not zero. I can't wrap my head around this. With the example of an electromagnet, I can imagine H to be the Magnetic intensity due to the current in the wire, but what about in the case of a bar magnet. What is the physical significance? What is producing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In electrostatics you also have that $\rm\bf{curl E} =0$ everywhere, that is $\oint \bf{E}\cdot d\bf{l} = 0$ for all loops but that does not mean that $\bf{E}=0$ everywhere. Instead it means that $\bf{E}=grad\phi$ for some scalar function $\phi$ everywhere; the same is with $\bf{H}$ in magnetostatics.

You may say that the fields $\bf{B}$ and $\bf{H}$ are the solenoidal $\rm{div} \bf{B}=0, \bf{B}=\rm\bf{curl A}$ and lamellar $\rm\bf{curl H} = 0, \bf{H}=\rm\bf{grad}\psi$ parts of the magnetization density $\bf{M}$, *resp*., see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) or Appendix B in Griffiths for details of this decomposition.

$$\bf{A(r)} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\rm\bf{curl}\bf{M(r')}}{|r-r'|}dV'\\
\psi(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int\frac{\rm{div}\bf{M(r')}}{|r-r'|}dV'$$

As you can see the *source* of $\bf{H}$ is the divergence of $\bf{M}$.

Comment: Thanks, I did understand the maths behind it, but my question was that does H have any physical significance in the case of a bar magnet as it does in the case of an electromagnet?

Comment: In a vacuum there is no difference between H and B (aside from a "non-physical" scaling factor). OTOH in a magnetized material the difference is what I described above. It does not matter what causes the magnetic polarization (external current or some other magnet), if there is polarized matter its own field is superposed and added to the external field.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field generated by a permanent magnet is produced by the combination of parallel magnetic dipole moments of the particles in the material of the magnet.

You can destroy this alignment by strong impacts or boiling the magnet. Which kind of illustrates that the magnetic property of the permanent magnet is caused by some kind of order at the atomic scale.